# python string.find() method does not take keyword arguments

Tags: python, string, find

I'm having a problem with the Python `string.find()` method. It seems to work just fine this way:

```
 p = mystr.find('id=')
```

It correctly returns the first match.

However, when I try to use the format with other arguments, like:

```
 p2 = mystr.find('id=', start=p+3)
```

It reports that: `find() not take keyword arguments`

I'm not sure what's going on here.

Comment: Thanks, @Robᵩ but I beg to differ. I asked this question because there is no straight solution in that any other questions. The answer of this question is more useful, right?

Comment: *Aside*: your title is incorrect. [`string.find()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find) **does** take keyword arguments, as your own answer indicates. [`str.find()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) **does not** take keyword arguments, as the question points out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `start`, directly give `p+3` like this

```
p2 = mystr.find('id=', p+3)
```

For example,

```
p = "id=id=1"
i = p.find("id=")
print p.find("id=", i + 3)
```

would print `3`

Answer (score 1):

I did not find where goes wrong, but I found a solution for this problem:-)

Just use find() in another way, like:

```
 import string as st
 p2 = st.find(mystr, 'id=', start=p+3)
```

works great :-)

Comment: This function is deprecated (http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#deprecated-string-functions).